# Aspnet C# call a particular function in postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Good afternoon, I'm learning aspnet, and web development, and I'm having a hard time understanding how I can call a certain postback function ... could anyone please answer me how do I do this...

codigo:

```js
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btnTest.Value = hid.Value;
        
    }

    protected void function2()
    {
        //param other function here
    }


}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>test postback</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doTest() {
            var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
            var hid = document.getElementById("hid");
            hid.value = nome.value;
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">    
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="nome" value="%%" name="nome" runat="server"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid" value="" runat="server" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnTest" runat="server" name="btnTest" value="button" onclick="doTest();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am only developing a small learning exercise, unfortunately I was asked to do so, so this is difficult to find information about this topic

Comment: You can also use OnClientClick like this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use html controls you have to use the `onserverclick` method:

```
<input runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="ButtonClick"/>
```

In you code behind:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //Your code goes here
}
```

You can also use the built in WebControls:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="ButtonClick"/>
```

The code behind would be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was researching and could not find ... Thank you.